How do I Cast CurrentPrincipal Identity in SharePoint Subscription Edition
In SharePoint 2019, with claims authentication enabled, I have a piece of code in my ASP.NET application that extracts the user identity from the current authenticated principal. The object extracted is of type System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity which I then cast to Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsIdentity using the snippet;
IClaimsIdentity identity = (ClaimsIdentity)Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity;
This works well in SharePoint 2019 but it fails in SharePoint Subscription Edition with the following error message;
[InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity' to type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsIdentity'.]
This leads me to believe that something changed in the internals of SharePoint Subscription Edition. How then would I perform this operation in SharePoint Subscription Edition?
Nothing is different other than the fact that I upgraded to SharePoint Subscription Edition.

SharePoint Subscription Edition seems to be supporting .Net Framework 4.8.
Based on this article, Beginning with .NET 4.5, System.Security.Claims classes should be used instead of those in the System.IdentityModel.Claims namespace. Probably at some point, Microsoft removed the backwards compatibility.
Check these images for how this change has been done: Identity Model Claims, New Claim Class - based on this, adjust your code.
"ICliamsIdentity extends this interface to access to claims collection. Windows Identity Foundation represents a claim within the Claim class."
In my case all I need to change was:
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims; to using System.Security.Claims;
((IClaimsIdentity) CurrentPrincipal.Identity) to (CurrentPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity)
IClaimsIdentity ClaimsIdentity references become ClaimsIdentity ClaimsIdentity
Please pay attention to the class differences - some properties have changed: e.g. claim.ClaimType becomes claim.Type (claim is an iteration variable from foreach (Claim claim in ClaimsIdentity.Claims)
Please let me know if this works for you or if I should add more details.
